# Why there are multiple peaks from the Fourier transform of a single sine signal?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have been reading about the Fourier Transform and its importance. To get a feel by visualizing it myself, I tried a few things.

- Plotted one signal and its Fourier transform
- Plotted 2 signals with a different frequency (but same amplitudes) and its Fourier transform
- Plotted 3 signals with different frequencies (but same amplitudes) and its Fourier transform

Here is what I got.

One signal and its Fourier transform:

[image]

Two signals and its Fourier transform:

[image]

Three signals and its Fourier transform:

[image]

Note: Orange lines represent the Fourier transform and blue lines the signal being processed.

I understand that Fourier transform helps to decompose the signals to give the ingredients of which the main signal is composed. In other words, we get the number of different frequencies of which the main signal is composed of.  But I do not understand the above outputs. If we consider the first signal where there is a single signal and its Fourier transform is calculated. Why there are 4 peaks? What does each peak represent? I had assumed the output to be a single peak for a single signal, 2 peaks for 2 signals and 3 peaks for 3 signals.

Here is the code that I used to generate the above images.

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.fftpack as fft
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    sample_points = np.arange(0,100,1)
    signal_1 = np.sin(sample_points) # 1x frequency
    signal_2 = np.sin(20*sample_points) # 20x frequency
    signal_3 = np.sin(100*sample_points) # 100x frequency

    combined_signal = signal_1 + signal_2

    fourier_transform = fft.fft(combined_signal)

    plt.plot(sample_points, combined_signal)
    plt.plot(sample_points, fourier_transform)
    plt.xlabel("Sample points")
    plt.gca().legend(('Combined Signal', 'Fourier Transform'))
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig("combined_signal_ft.png")

    plt.clf()

    plt.plot(sample_points, signal_1)
    plt.plot(sample_points, fft.fft(signal_1))
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig("mono_ft.png")

    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(sample_points, signal_1 + signal_2 + signal_3)
    plt.plot(sample_points, fft.fft(signal_1 + signal_2 + signal_3))
    plt.savefig("tri_ft.png")
```

Comment: Maybe this can be of help to you: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/why-is-the-fft-mirrored

Comment: @JustenIngels How do we then explain those 2 peaks (for a single signal)

Comment: It's not two peaks, it's one peak, but an FFT is always mirror-symmetric.  Only the first half is actually useful.  Think of it this way: an FFT can't pick up signal data at more than half the sampling rate.  When you try you get essentially garbage data that just so happens to be a mirrored refection of the "real" FFT. I probably jut gave some mathematcian a coronary, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: @DanielF The first half also has 2 peaks. One a very small and other a high peak.

Comment: This is imho more suited for StackExchange Signal Processing, since there is no programming issue involved.

Comment: What are you even plotting? You write "peaks", so I assume you want to plot the amplitude, but the amplitude is not negative... Note that the transformed signal is complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scipy.fftpack.fft` returns both positive & negative frequencies, you only need the positive frequencies which in your code are stored in `fourier_transform[1:len(signal)/2]`. [See scipy.fftpack.fft documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html)

The mathematics of discrete Fourier transforms has to take into account negative frequencies due to the periodic nature of the sine & cosine functions, more information [here.](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/mdft/Positive_Negative_Frequencies.html)

Comment: Sharing it here. This is one of the best intuitive explanation for Fourier transformation and FFTs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjmwwDHT98c